# Django EmailMessage with Text/Plain Attachment Sends Garbled File

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, email, django-2.0

I've been trying to send an email with an attachment by Django. The steps are as below:

```
msg = EmailMessage(
    "Test",
    "This is testing.",
    to=["foo@bar.com"],
    attachments=[
        ("test.txt", b"This is a text.", "text/plain")
    ]
)
msg.send()
```

However, the attachment that I'm getting is a garbled text:

```
N¬Æ­{
```

The below is what I got with `hexdump` from the attachment file in case it might be helpful:

```
0000000 184e 8aac adc6 1b7b                    
0000008
```

I've also tried the methods below (explicitly defining mimetype):

- `attach` method on `EmailMessage` instance with either string and binary
- `attach_file` method on `EmailMessage` instance with either string and binary

However, with these methods, I've got (i) either a garbled result or (ii) an oddly empty attachment.

So, is there something I don't know about attaching a simple string to the email?

---

## Environment

- Testing on Manjaro (if the test machine affects my results, maybe?)
- Python 3.5.6
- Django 2.0.4

Comment: Do `attachments=[("test.txt", "This is a text.", "text/plain")]` instead

Comment: Still got the garbled result. I've also tried `encode` to bytes and then `decode` back to string again. :/

Comment: It's titled correctly ?

Comment: Changed title, no luck.